# Cannot connect to KAFKA running on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, docker, apache-kafka

I have created an App Service in Azure and loaded a docker compose as shown below

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  zoo1:
    image: zookeeper:3.4.9
    hostname: zoo1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
        ZOO_MY_ID: 1
        ZOO_PORT: 2181
        ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.1
    hostname: kafka1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_INTERNAL://kafka1:29092,LISTENER_EXTERNAL://kafka1:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_INTERNAL://kafka1:29092,LISTENER_EXTERNAL://dev-my-public-host-kafka.azurewebsites.net:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_INTERNAL

      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
```

Then I am trying to connect to this KAFKA using npm-kafka

```
const KAFKA_SERVER='dev-my-public-host-kafka.azurewebsites.net:9092'
const client = new kafka.KafkaClient({ kafkaHost: KAFKA_SERVER });
```

This seems to not working. I am getting connection refused.

Comment: Why aren't you using Confluent Zookeeper image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access any other ports than 80 and 443 on Azure Web Apps from the internet/any process not in the same sandboxed app. From [the docs](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#network-endpoint-listening):

> The only way an application can be accessed via the internet is through the already-exposed HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443) TCP ports; applications may not listen on other ports for packets arriving from the internet.
>   However, applications may create a socket which can listen for connections from within the sandbox. For example, two processes within the same app may communicate with one another via TCP sockets; connection attempts incoming from outside the sandbox, albeit they be on the same machine, will fail. See the next topic for additional detail.

So, if you want to connect to Kafka from the outside you need to change your configuration to use allowed ports or you could use another Azure Offering, like Virtual Machines, Container Instances, AKS, ServiceFabric etc. if you want to expose other ports.

Comment: So I'm not an Azure user, but Docker Compose can be submitted to it?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, but it is in preview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-multi-container

Answer (score 0):

Your external listener is the same as the internal. You'll need to open up all addresses

```
LISTENER_EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092
```

For simplicity, you could use Azure EventHubs instead or run your code in an container as well

You could also use AKS instead rather than Compose on a single machine